# User Auto Login After A month php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, session, session-cookies

I've been trying to implement users auto login feature for a while now and i've not suceeded in making it work. Below is the code i've been trying with no success at all

```
    <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","friendzo_ne");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  $expire = 365*24*3600; // We choose a one year duration
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $expire);
session_start();
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$expire); 
if (isset($_SESSION['user_login'])){
$user = $_SESSION["user_login"];    
}
else
{
    "";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the intent of this code? This looks like boilerplate session code, and nothing user-specific other than testing that session value. You're going to need to be more clear about your objective.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: what I'm looking at achieving is resuming user session

Comment: This really depends on what that means in terms of your code so unless you can describe how that works, we can only really guess. Note that this is a solved problem, there are many field-tested, secure, community supported login systems and I *strongly encourage* you to find one of these that fits your needs and use that instead of rolling your own. Self-built login systems are extremely hard to get right, and even the tiniest mistake means your site is vulnerable.